# How can I fire "onUnselect" event on jQuery Easy UI Datagrid row object?

Tags: jquery, datagrid, jquery-easyui

the changelog said the bug has been fixed, but I still can not fire "onUnselect" event on jQuery Easy UI Datagrid row object, also "onSelect".

I am using version 1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Can you try,(it should work), if not, post your codings.

```
$('#dg').datagrid({
    onSelect: function(rowIndex, rowData)
    {

        //your stuff
    },
    onUnselect: function(rowIndex, rowData){

        //your stuff
    },
    onUnselectAll: function(rows){

        //your stuff
    }
});
```

Make sure datagrid property singleSelect="true".

Comment: thank you, of couse I wrote that code, but it just can not fire the event <code>  $('#manhour').datagrid({
    singleSelect: true,
    url: "/manager_project/show/<%= @id %>",
    columns:[[
      {field:'hours',title:'工数', width:50,editor:{
          type: 'numberbox',
          options:{
            precision:2
          }
        }
      }
    ]],
    onSelect:function(rowIndex){
      $('#manhour').datagrid('beginEdit', rowIndex);
    },
    onUnselect:function(rowIndex){
      $('#manhour').datagrid('endEdit', rowIndex);
    }
  });</code>

Comment: There is no problem with the code which you posted. But please check where the code resides, i.e did you placed the code under some conditional blocks(if.. else..).